awk/sed to get a particular field extracted
I have below file data which i want to parse and filter to get the Volumes names from 4th field nd thereby I want to extract the last string starting with ^fsvol-.
Data File:
C0BF4EE2-1381
Completed       pod_a0_4    Success volume/fs-04b/fsvol-07     FSx     May 13, 2024, 19:15:08 (UTC+05:30)      May 14, 2024, 03:15:08 (UTC+05:30)
C55114AF-E488
Completed       pod_a0_3    Success volume/fs-04b/fsvol-02     FSx     May 13, 2024, 19:14:56 (UTC+05:30)      May 14, 2024, 03:14:56 (UTC+05:30)
D7AE9EF8-C573
Completed       pod_a0_2    Success volume/fs-04b/fsvol-08     FSx     May 13, 2024, 19:14:44 (UTC+05:30)      May 14, 2024, 03:14:44 (UTC+05:30)
0C662A8C-CD25
Completed       pod_a0_1    Success volume/fs-04b/fsvol-0a     FSx     May 13, 2024, 19:14:33 (UTC+05:30)      May 14, 2024, 03:14:33 (UTC+05:30)

Test Trial & results:
(devcli) $ sed -n  '/^Completed/s/.*\(fsvol-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/p' test-fil1001
fsvol-07
fsvol-02
fsvol-08
fsvol-0a
(devcli) $ awk  '/^Completed/{match($4, /fsvol-[a-zA-Z0-9]+/); print substr($4, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' test-fil1001
fsvol-07
fsvol-02
fsvol-08
fsvol-0a
(devcli) $ awk  '/^Completed/{print $4}' test-fil1001 | cut -d'/' -f3
fsvol-07
fsvol-02
fsvol-08
fsvol-0a

I have tried above and that is working but looking for a best to way to do it with little shorter version or elegant way.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to code review, your own code is working.

Of course that's code review. He had working solutions.

This is definitely a programming problem though

You can get this done, using a single awk command:
awk '/^Completed/ && split($4, a, /\//) >= 3 {print a[3]}' file

fsvol-07
fsvol-02
fsvol-08
fsvol-0a


Using /^Completed/ we are making sue lines start with Completed.
split($4, a, /\//) >= 3 splits 4th column by / character and makes sure that we have at least 3 elements in array a after split.
print a[3] prints 3rd element of the split array

